# How to stop output in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, usrp

I'm building a Transmitter and Receiver with two Ettus N210 USRPs using Matlab & Simlink.
I can send data from the Transmitter to the Receiver, and the Receiver is receiving the correct data.

My problem is: There is a continuous output.

I would like to only send one single message, but I can't seem to figure out how to only send a single message.

Is this even possible?

Thanks for any help!

Best regards,

Emily

Comment: You mean you want the signal to be zero after a while? make it zero after a while

Comment: I don't want to have a signal at all. I just want to send a single message and then no output after that. Without stopping the whole simulation

Comment: What is "no output". Zero? You can't make something cease to exist, erase it from earth. A phone that is turned off is sending zero signal. Figure you what "none" means for your signal, and output that. Generally, that means zero.

Comment: perhaps you would like to share the Simulink block diagram tou currently use with the readers of your question, attaching it to the question, or with a acreenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing the block that sends data inside an enabled subsystem.

You can then have a signal that enables the sub-system only when the signal transmission is required.